# mysql UNION wrong result?

Tags: mysql

I have query like this

```
(SELECT s1.m as m,IFNULL(s2.y,2013) as y,IFNULL(s2.s,0) as planned FROM
(SELECT 1 as m 
UNION SELECT 2 
UNION SELECT 3 
UNION SELECT 4 
UNION SELECT 5 
UNION SELECT 6 
UNION SELECT 7 
UNION SELECT 8 
UNION SELECT 9 
UNION SELECT 10 
UNION SELECT 11   
UNION SELECT 12) s1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT YEAR(p.pdate2) as y,MONTH(p.pdate2) as m, SUM(p.totwdisc) as s FROM   pro_partial_inv p WHERE YEAR(p.pdate2)=2013 GROUP BY y,m) s2
ON s1.m=s2.m)
UNION
(SELECT s5.m as m,IFNULL(s3.y,2013) as y,IFNULL(s3.s,0) as realv FROM
(SELECT 1 as m 
UNION SELECT 2 
UNION SELECT 3 
UNION SELECT 4 
UNION SELECT 5 
UNION SELECT 6 
UNION SELECT 7 
UNION SELECT 8 
UNION SELECT 9 
UNION SELECT 10 
UNION SELECT 11   
UNION SELECT 12) s5
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT YEAR(p.paidd) as y,MONTH(p.paidd) as m, SUM(p.totwdisc) as s FROM  pro_partial_inv p WHERE p.status=2 AND YEAR(p.paidd)=2013 GROUP BY y,m) s3
ON s5.m=s3.m)
UNION
(SELECT s6.m as m,IFNULL(s4.y,2013) as y,IFNULL(s4.s,0) as proj FROM
(SELECT 1 as m 
UNION SELECT 2 
UNION SELECT 3 
UNION SELECT 4 
UNION SELECT 5 
UNION SELECT 6 
UNION SELECT 7 
UNION SELECT 8 
UNION SELECT 9 
UNION SELECT 10 
UNION SELECT 11   
UNION SELECT 12) s6
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT YEAR(p.startd) as y,MONTH(p.startd) as m, SUM(p.disc_n) as s FROM pro_project  p WHERE YEAR(p.startd)=2013 GROUP BY y,m) s4
ON s6.m=s4.m)
```

So I need it to be like this:

```
m       y     planned

1   2013    0.00    
2   2013    0.00    
3   2013    0.00    
4   2013    0.00    
5   2013    0.00    
6   2013    908.18    
7   2013    0.00    
8   2013    1136.36    
9   2013    13354.54    
10  2013    0.00    
11  2013    0.00    
12  2013    0.00    
1   2013    0.00    
2   2013    0.00    
3   2013    0.00    
4   2013    0.00    
5   2013    0.00    
6   2013    908.18    
7   2013    0.00    
8   2013    1136.36    
9   2013    13354.54    
10  2013    0.00    
11  2013    0.00    
12  2013    0.00
1   2013    0.00    
2   2013    0.00    
3   2013    0.00    
4   2013    0.00    
5   2013    0.00    
6   2013    908.18    
7   2013    0.00    
8   2013    1136.36    
9   2013    13354.54    
10  2013    0.00    
11  2013    0.00    
12  2013    0.00
```

it is like 3 unions that look very similar but are different. m represents month, y year and planned values from calculation. The result I get is this:

```
m       y     planned

1   2013    0.00    
2   2013    0.00    
3   2013    0.00    
4   2013    0.00    
5   2013    0.00    
6   2013    908.18    
7   2013    0.00    
8   2013    1136.36    
9   2013    13354.54    
10  2013    0.00    
11  2013    0.00    
12  2013    0.00
6   2013    0.00
7   2013    809.09
8   2013    2227.27
9   2013    0.00
7   2013    43600.00
8   2013    41330.00
```

Am I doing something wrong? probably am but I am not sure why is here not made union 3 times, when I run the queries separated I get good result.

Comment: this query hurts my brain.  I would love if it were possible to replace those UNION's by a WHERE IN (2,3,4,5,6,7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the two `UNION`s need to be changed to `UNION ALL` between the three "major" queries.  That prevents duplicates from being removed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I think you can replace each of the 3 inner sections with something like :

```
(SELECT s2.m as m,IFNULL(s2.y,2013) as y,IFNULL(s2.s,0) as planned FROM
(SELECT YEAR(p.pdate2) as y,MONTH(p.pdate2) as m, SUM(p.totwdisc) as s FROM pro_partial_inv p WHERE YEAR(p.pdate2)=2013 GROUP BY y,m) s2
WHERE s2.m in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
```

or even this:

```
(SELECT s2.m as m,IFNULL(s2.y,2013) as y,IFNULL(s2.s,0) as planned FROM
(SELECT YEAR(p.pdate2) as y,MONTH(p.pdate2) as m, SUM(p.totwdisc) as s FROM pro_partial_inv p WHERE YEAR(p.pdate2)=2013 GROUP BY y,m) s2
WHERE s2.m != 1)
```

in fact - correct me if I've oversimplified and lost something - but I think you can reduce each inner section to :

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(p.pdate2) as y,
    MONTH(p.pdate2) as m, 
    SUM(p.totwdisc) as planned
FROM pro_partial_inv p 
WHERE y=2013 AND m != 1
GROUP BY y,m
```